# Indicator LED on a switch with no neutral - impossible, right?

Tags: led, resistors, switches

I have a switch in my bathroom that switches the floor heating (a resistive load of 180 Ω, corresponding to a power of 300 W @ 230 VAC) on/off. I'm considering replacing the manual switch with an [Aqara T1 single switch module - no neutral](https://www.aqara.com/en/single_switch_T1_no-neutral.html). However, since the Aqara module will be hidden, and the manual switch will be removed, there will be no easy way to see, in the bathroom, whether the floor heating is on or off. So I considered adding an LED of some sort, but when I tried drawing the schematic, it occurred to me that that's impossible - right?

Comment: Lit when off is easy. Voltage across switch is high when off
 || Lit when on cam be achieved with a current transformer.- 1 turn primary to many turn secondary.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, The current transformer is a clever idea—maybe should be an _Answer_ — but do you think there's any available product that would fit the bill? I got curious and Googled for "current transformer." Most products appear to be designed for measuring large currents—hundreds to thousands of Amperes—and their secondaries all are rated for 5A ("standard meter output" apparently.) They're kind of pricey, and they mostly look too big to fit inside a wall. I reckon OP will want a turns ratio of maybe 100:1 or 200:1.

Comment: You could connect a neon lamp or a pair of anti-parallel LEDS through a 100k - 220k resistor from the switched hot side to the safety ground. With no more than 2 mA it would not pose any risk of shock, and would be below threshold of a GFCI. But probably not up to code, so proceed at your own risk.

Comment: [here](https://nz.rs-online.com/web/p/current-transformers/1243896) is a small 50/60 Hz rated current transformer that shows what can be achieved at a reasonable price.  [Datasheete here](https://docs.rs-online.com/46fc/0900766b81537b77.pdf). [RS are 'expensive' so this is maybe a $3 part.] Note that as is this is NOT suitable as it gives far too low Vout at desired max current. A similar result could be acheived by taking a small mains to low voltage transformer, stripping off the low voltage secondary and adding a 1 or few turn winding of thick wire for the target circuit. ...

Comment: ... This can be discussed in more detail in an answer IF of possible interest.

Comment: You may not have read the above comments (as the accepted answer (which is a good one) is the same as my comments above) . [The answer is good and directly addresses your requirement.]. || The CR2550 can be bought from the manufacturer at about 40% of the Digikey price [here](https://www.crmagnetics.com/remote/cr2550). || [Datasheet here](https://www.crmagnetics.com/Assets/ProductPDFs/2550.pdf) - note that the R model turns on the LED at 0.55 Amps in the main conductor. The A and G models turn on at 1.55A. You can double the sensitivity by using two turns in the looped main wire.

Comment: ... You can reduce sensitivity by adding one or more sweries diodes or a zener diode in the LED lead. || Probably you should NEVER operate these with LED disconnected as voltage may rise to beyond device survival limits (deep-ending on the design). || As above, you can build one of these yourself by stripping the secondary winding from a very small mains to low voltage transformer and adding a single or few turn winding. this must NEVER be unloaded.

Comment: CR2550-R also on Amazon [here](https://www.amazon.com/CR-Magnetics-Remote-Current-Indicator/dp/B006K3O1MY) at slightly above manufactrurers price. Shipping may be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A current-sensing transformer and indicator may suit - provided an indication only when current is flowing is satisfactory. (i.e., If the switch is on but a thermostat or other control in the load switches itself off the current would drop and the indication turn off.)

[image]

*Figure 1. An image deliberately obscured so as not to be a product recommendation.*

Comment: Oh, that's brilliant! That's a lot of money for an indicator light, but that's a *really* neat solution.

Comment: Probably you should mention that only _one_ of the conductors leading to the switch should be threaded through the hole.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want:

1. You want it to be lit when the switch is off (i.e. to be able to find the switch in the dark): That's easy, because than you just wire your LED (or preferably a neon indicator) parallel to the switch.
2. You want it to be lit when the switch is on: you need a connection to neutral
3. You want it to be lit all the time: you need a connection to neutral

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8nHAR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In case 1 keep in mind that this might give you trouble with small loads like LED bulbs and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the manual for it and one way you can do it is to connect the indicator to the load terminal of the module.

Comment: But where does the *other* wire of the indicator go to?

Comment: Parallel with the load

Answer (score 1):

Consider a **neon indicator** in parallel with the load.  Or alternatively a piece of **fibre optic** to the indicator on the switch module.

Comment: The question is about how to put the indicator on the **switch** where there is no neutral. The load is hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but without knowledge of the layout it's difficult to know where the questioner wants to connect.